# Exclude dev dependencies when publishing npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

So I'm in the process of publishing a package to npm. It is basically just a simple module that lets users make Ajax calls and can be configured in a few ways.

I have read that it is a good idea to test the install locally and tried that. I have packed the package via the "npm pack" command, change into another directory and then tried installing the packge via "npm install path-to-file-that-was-just-created.tgz".
So far everything works, I have a node_modules folder, that contains my bundled code.

However, is also has installed all the dependencies that I have listed as devDependencies in the package.json of my actual module, even though the only the bundled file is needed and no other depenedencies are defined.
I have tried updating the npm-shrinkwrap.json, and checked that every dependency has the dev property marked as true.

The goal is actually for the user to install this module and then have no dependencies installed, because they do not need babel or mocha, to run the module.
How can I exclude these from the packge?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `npm pack`, but if you publish your module normally, when they `npm install your-module-name`, `devDependencies` are not installed by default unless they explicitly navigate to your module in `node_modules` and run `npm install`.

Comment: so it might be something that just happens when I install it locally the way I did to test it. I will have to check that, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

use the --production flag to avoid installing dev dependencies

For published modules, you don't need to do anything, when a user installs your library, only the non-dev dependencies will be installed

Comment: I have just tried that but it does not seem to work strangely. It still installs all my dev dependencies. I have checked the package.json, the npm-shrinkwrap.json, all dependencies are marked as dev : true or listed under devDependencies but still they get installed.
I did manage to get them excluded by adding the shrinkwrap file to my npmignore, but i still think it should work anyway

Comment: @marcus_deh the "dev packages" could also be a dependency of a different package that you require

Comment: But shouldn't there actually be no additional dependencies when I am just distributing a bundled js file? Because that's what I'm trying to do. Otherwise I'm sure the must be something wrong the way I set the package up for punishing.

Comment: Works in node.js 6

Answer (score 4):

If you want your published module to have no dependencies but you still need to have some to build it you can also try to use this command before publishing:

```
npx json -f package.json -I -e "delete this.devDependencies"
```

This way only works in CI/CD.

Update: it turned out that `npm pkg delete devDependencies` does the same without any additional dependency

Comment: This is the right answer!

I extracted this functionality (and a bit more) into a package called "lean-package"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lean-package

Answer (score 2):

After running your install, you can prune dev dependencies by running this command:
`npm prune --production`

this will keep only production dependencies.  Documentation from [npm here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-prune):

> If the --production flag is specified or the NODE_ENV environment
> variable is set to production, this command will remove the packages
> specified in your devDependencies